# Delimit multiple columns in a date frame based on ':', within that same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, delimiter

I realise there are many questions asking something similar but I just cannot replicate those solutions.

I have a data frame as follows:

```
 vcf<-data.frame(
   v1 = c(10, 15, 30),
   v2 = c(10, 30, 80),
   v3 = c(3,4,7),
   v4 = as.factor(c('4:4:3','.','.')),
   v5 = as.factor(c('4:7:2','4:2:7','3:5:7'))
 )
```

What I want to achieve is the final two columns split into six columns total:

```
vcf2<-data.frame(
     v1 = c(10, 15, 30),
     v2 = c(10, 30, 80),
     v3 = c(3,4,7),
     v4 = as.factor(c(4,'.','.')),
     v5 = as.factor(c(4,'.','.')),
     v6 = as.factor(c(3,'.','.')),
     v7 = as.factor(c(4,4,3)),
     v8 = as.factor(c(7,2,5)),
     v9 = as.factor(c(2,7,7))
   )
```

So far I have tried solutions from other posts, the one I felt most hopeful with was as follows:

```
within(vcf, vcf$v4<-data.frame(do.call('rbind',strsplit(as.character(vcf$v4), '\\:', fixed=TRUE))))
```

But it didn't come close.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse the data and read it with the `:` separator

```
read.table(text=sub("NA",".:.:.",do.call(paste,c(sep=':',vcf))),sep=":")

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1 10 10  3  4  4  3  4  7  2
2 15 30  4  .  .  .  4  2  7
3 30 80  7  .  .  .  3  5  7
```

To convert the above, just add the argument `na.strings="."` ie:
`read.table(text=sub("NA",".:.:.",do.call(paste,c(sep=':',vcf))),sep=":",na.strings = ".")`

You can also write a recursive method using `separate` since separate only works at one column at a time:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 M = function(df,x,i=1,...){
  df = separate(df,x[i],paste0(x[i],1:3),...)
  if (i==length(x)) df else M(df,x,i+1,...)
}
M(vcf,c("v4","v5"))
  v1 v2 v3  v41  v42  v43 v51 v52 v53
1 10 10  3    4    4    3   4   7   2
2 15 30  4 <NA> <NA> <NA>   4   2   7
3 30 80  7 <NA> <NA> <NA>   3   5   7
```

To convert the type to numeric:

```
M(vcf,c("v4","v5"),convert=T)
  v1 v2 v3 v41 v42 v43 v51 v52 v53
1 10 10  3   4   4   3   4   7   2
2 15 30  4  NA  NA  NA   4   2   7
3 30 80  7  NA  NA  NA   3   5   7
```

Comment: I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but when I run your first solution I get: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 9 elements`.

Comment: With the second I get `could not find function "separate"`

Comment: can you add the argument `fill=TRUE` and see what happens?

Comment: @FatBerg you first have to load the library `tidyr` to obtain the function `separate`ie you can first run `library(tidyverse)` or `library(tidyr)` before you run the code

Comment: Ah yeah that works great thanks. Regarding your first suggestion the output was closer, but rows 2 and 3 had their right-most values shifted to the left in place of the NA values.

Comment: @FatBerg so in essence you have more NA in some rows, while the code I gave only works with the specific columns. So you will need to select the columns you specifically want to separate and run the code on them then cbind them back together to your data. eg `read.table(...vcf[c("v4","v5")]...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringr::str_split_fixed`:

```
library(stringr)

vcf_new <- cbind(vcf,str_split_fixed(vcf$v4, ":",3), str_split_fixed(vcf$v5, ":",3))

# drop the split columns
vcf_new <- vcf_new[,-c(4,5)]

# fix the names
names(vcf_new) <- paste0("v", seq(1,9))

# get rid of factors
vcf_new <- apply(vcf_new, 2, as.numeric)

     v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9
[1,] 10 10  3  4  4  3  4  7  2
[2,] 15 30  4 NA NA NA  4  2  7
[3,] 30 80  7 NA NA NA  3  5  7
```

If you want periods instead of `NA`s, you need to convert to character types, but this will work: `vcf_new[is.na(vcf_new)] <- '.'`

Comment: This is great, thanks. I will work on it myself, but if I have dozens of columns (say 50, v4 to v54), could you advise on how to loop over each?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `data.table::tstrsplit`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(vcf)

vcf[, paste0('v', 4:9) := sapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ':')
    , .SDcols = c('v4', 'v5')]

vcf

#    v1 v2 v3 v4   v5   v6 v7 v8 v9
# 1: 10 10  3  4    4    3  4  7  2
# 2: 15 30  4  . <NA> <NA>  4  2  7
# 3: 30 80  7  . <NA> <NA>  3  5  7
```